# How do I convert units in Globulation?

Tags: globulation-2

In the description of an AI (ReachToInfinity) it's mentioned that it will aggressively convert units. What does that mean? Can I do the same and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://globulation2.org/wiki/Fruit_and_conversion

Checking the "fV" (food vision) and "mV" (market vision) options in the alliance menu will allow other teams to see where your inns and markets are. Although this lets opponents know a lot about where your globs are based, it also allows you to entice their globs into converting over to your side. If your inns advertise a wider variety of fruit than anyone else's, enemy globs will convert to your team in droves. The number of globs who have converted to and from your team is indicated by the last pair of numbers in the top line of the Globulation 2 screen. Even if you don't use a strategy of conversion, you may still need to defend yourself in case an enemy team tries to convert your globs.

Comment: Seems like a tactics that is hard to utilize. But I will try it out. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It *is* difficult to convert units consistently. Build a lot of inns -- dozens of them. Upgrade them as much as you can. Build inns near fruit; build inns close to the battle front. The fruit must be visible (to the workers, not just to you). Build a tower near each fruit grove; this has the double benefit of ensuring it's visible and discouraging enemy workers from harvesting. Fruit never runs out but if enemy inns don't have a nice variety, units will convert to your team... and your units won't convert to the enemy.

Beware that eating fruit means losing armor. If your inns are full of fruit and enemy inns are not, your warriors will be weaker in combat. But conversion is worth it.